# AppleScript: Moving an iCal event to the next day

Tags: scripting, calendar, applescript, osx-mavericks, icalendar

Greetings and Merry Christmas.

I have a schedule that is being imported incorrectly into my calendar for work. I work overnight so the segments after Midnight are not being created on the next calendar day like they should be.

I want to write an AppleScript that looks at all events in that Calendar week, and moves them to the next day if they occur between 00:00:00 AM to 12:00:00 PM

I am working very slowly at building this. After I succeed with modifying one day I will create a nested loop to do the whole week.

Here is my code. It will isolate the events that need moved and even move them to the next day but it does not retain the correct start and end times for the event.

Example - Event is at 2:00 AM tomorrow, current time is 3:00 PM. I run the script to move it to tomorrow and the event will move, but get a new start and end time equal to 3:00 PM

```
tell application "Calendar"
activate
set tomorrow to ((current date) + 1 * days)
set theDate to (current date)
set yesterday to ((current date) - 1 * days)
set time of theDate to 12 * hours
set time of yesterday to 24 * hours

tell calendar "myCalendar"
    set x to events whose (start date < theDate)
    repeat with i in x
        if start date of i > yesterday then
            show i
            set start date of i to tomorrow
            set end date of i to tomorrow
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
end tell
```

I understand it might not be the most optimized code, just looking for any help you can offer. It will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: May be you can set the start date like this "set start date of i to (start date of i) + (1 * days)" (you catch my drift) and don't change anything else (end date, time).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. VERY Interesting outcome, but with a little fanangaling I got it to work!!! Thanks a ton! Without your help I would not have gotten it so easily. Funny that you have to change the END date before changing the start date in my case!!

Comment: Post that as the answer and I will accept it!